# Can someone please tell me why my code sometimes still prints out empty spaces as part of the generated password?

Tags: python

```
import random 

password = list(' ' * 12)


symbolsList = ['!', '.', '#', '$', '%', '&', '/', '(', ')', 
'*', '+', "\'", ",", "\\", '_']
numbersList = str([i + 1 for i in range(9)])
lowercaseList = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 
'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
uppercaseList = [x.upper() for x in lowercaseList]

def create_password():
    i = 0

    while i < 12:
        choice = random.randint(1, 4)
        if choice == 1:
            word = random.choice(symbolsList)
            password[i] = word
        if choice == 2:
            word = random.choice(numbersList)
            password[i] = word
        if choice == 3:
            word = random.choice(lowercaseList)
            password[i] = word
        if choice == 4:
            word = random.choice(uppercaseList)
            password[i] = word
        i += 1
    print(''.join(password))

create_password()
```

I know this is nowhere near optimal code, but I'm new to this so I just wanted to make it work. The generator works by creating a list of 12 empty strings. There are banks of characters that can make up the password. The while loop makes it choose what kind of character to place, and also which of the type it should place. At the end, the list is joined together and printed out as a string

Comment: Paste your example output

Comment: `numbersList` is not what you think it is

Comment: Stringifying a list makes something... interesting.

Comment: as @ThisFieldIsRequired tells you, you have stringfied a list so numbers list is actually a string that looks like `'[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]'` so it has spaces and commas etc in it. hence a space can be seleted from the numbers list

Comment: You'd be much better off using the [`string`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html) module... `numberedList = string.digits`...

Answer (score 1):

That because of this line:

```
numbersList = str([i + 1 for i in range(9)])
```

You have set the numbersList to String not the elements of numberList
It should be like following:

```
numbersList = [str(i + 1) for i in range(9)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You initiated your numberList wrongly, as you made one string out of the list. Instead of:

```
numbersList = str([i + 1 for i in range(9)])
```

try this:

```
numbersList = [str(i + 1) for i in range(9)]
```

or even better (so you can have 0-9 digits):

```
numbersList = [str(i) for i in range(10)]
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `numbersList`.
If do this, you will get a string:

```
numbersList = str([i + 1 for i in range(9)])
```

The string you get is:

```
'[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]'
```

So `random.choice(numberList)` will give an answer in:

```
['[',
 '1',
 ',',
 ' ',
 '2',
 ',',
 ' ',
 '3',
 ',',
 ' ',
 '4',
 ',',
 ' ',
 '5',
 ',',
 ' ',
 '6',
 ',',
 ' ',
 '7',
 ',',
 ' ',
 '8',
 ',',
 ' ',
 '9',
 ']']
```

It's not what you want.

You should replace it to:

```
numbersList = [str(i + 1) for i in range(9)]
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

This will do.

Answer (score 0):

numbersList is not a list of numbers, it is a string that is literally equal to '[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]' . On your `choice==2` section, there is a good chance you will receive a space...
What you meant was probably

```
numbersList = [str(i+1) for i in range(9)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a somewhat more optimized code for your problem as well, you might want to take a look at it

```
fullList = ['!', '.', '#', '$', '%', '&', '/', '(', ')', '*', '+', "\'", ",", "\\", '_'] + list(string.ascii_letters) + [str(x) for x in range(1, 10)]

def create_password():
    outp = ''
    for i in range(12):
        outp += random.choice(fullList)
    return outp

print(create_password())
```

If you want to use list comprehensions for even less code you can use:

```
def create_password():
    return ''.join(random.choice(fullList) for x in range(12))
```